# Quelle est la signication de « prendre en garantie » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire, québec, droit-et-justice

J'ai trouvé cette expression dans un roman québecois. Deux personnages prennent la voiture d'un troixième (en fait, ils la volent) et une des deux dit:

> On va y aller avec ça. C’est un char que Steven **a pris en garantie**. Il va vouloir me tuer, mais au point où je suis rendue…

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre quelle est la signification de *acheter en garantie* une voiture. Est-ce un contrat de leasing?

Answer (score 5):

Au Québec quand on dit *prendre en garantie* c'est que l'on va laisser quelque chose en garantie, soit en attente d'un retour, d'un paiement ou d'une action.

Par exemple:

> Lorsqu'on va louer un véhicule qui sera utilisé sur un circuit fermé,
> il est commun que le commerçant prenne le permis de conduire en
> garantie.
>
> Un prêteur pourrait demander de prendre un hypothèque en garantie sur
> la maison, comme ça si le paiement ne vient pas, il aura un recours
> possible.
>
> Quelqu'un te demande de lui rendre en service, il pourrait prendre un
> objet auquel tu tiens en garantie en attendant que le service soit
> rendu.

Comment: A ma connaissance l'emploi est le même en Belgique au moins (et je me risquerais à dire qu'en France également, mais ca demanderait confirmation)